# At the anode of a forward biased diode what sustains the flow of electrons from the metal of the ohmic contact to the positive side of the supply?

Tags: diodes

1. Although we usually consider current in a schematic wire to consist of positive charge carriers, we know that in reality it is the flow of conduction band electrons.
2. Therefore, at the ohmic contact on the anode side of a diode, when the diode is forward biased, electrons will flow from the metal contact into the connecting wire and into the positive terminal of the battery.
3. Given that ALL of the forward biased current within the body of the diode consists of the diffusion of majority and minority carriers (see figure below), ***how are the electrons in the metal contact at the anode side of the diode replenished?***
4. More specifically, what are the mechanisms that occur which enable a drift current of electrons out of the metal and a diffusion of holes in the opposite direction (toward the junction) to form a constant current across the ohmic contact?

[image]

Comment: 3) They come from the cathode.

Comment: Are the answers you have here sufficient? Or are you looking for something that covers the statistics of diffusion and drift currents of both polarities?

Comment: Andy, my diagram clearly shows electrons entering the contact attached to the cathode.   My question asks how electrons in the contact on the ANODE side are resupplied to that contact since the current into the diode from that  contact consists almost entirely of hole diffusion.  Jonk, thank-you for your response.  Yes, I was looking for an explanation of the action at the contact to the anode which allows diffusion of holes in the anode toward the n-side to produce a drift of electrons from that contact to the supply.  I would expect an an energy band diagram answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's all electrons. When we talk about a "hole" moving left-to-right, that's just shorthand for the fact that an electron moved right-to-left from the hole's new position to its old position.

Comment: Dave, thank you for your reply.  What you say about holes is true and is something I have known for more than 30 years.  Given that the current flow at the contact side of the anode consists almost entirely of hole diffusion (electron diffusion in the valence band) my question had more to do with how those electrons cross into the metal contact to become drift current in the wire. However, in thinking about your answer I am somewhat led to my own answer.  These valence band electrons must become the drift current.  I guess I was hoping for a little more detail on how they cross into the metal.

Comment: For that, you'll want to look into the details of an "[ohmic contact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohmic_contact)". It is in fact one of the more complicated issues associated with semiconductor fabrication.

Comment: Contact fabrication, especially in something like a 14nm FinFET process is possibly the single most complex part of the entire process.  Agreed. However, that is a separate issue.  Actually, I was looking to see if I could get a compact and substantive explanation in terms of energy band diagrams of how electron diffusion in the valence band (holes) transfers into drift current coming out of the metal.  Doesn't look like I'll get an answer for that.  One commentator clearly did not even understand my question.  Anyway, thanks again for your response.  I appreciate the effort!